# Unlock Windows 10 laptop with docking station or office network

Tags: windows-10, laptop, security

I have a Lenovo T430 running Win10 and in my office I drop it into a docking station.

Is there a way that I can have it automatically log me in by identifying any of the following:

- Connecting to the office network (LAN or Wifi)
- Dropped into docking station
- Geo-location??

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by unlock?

Comment: Be able to open the laptop or restore from sleep and not have to type in the password.

Comment: Okay, do you use a domain account to log into your laptop at your office?

Comment: Individual user

Comment: Okay, I am looking right now.  Although, I don't know any methods to have it log in automatically based on your criteria unless its a domain account.  (Not a local profile)  I will share if I find anything.  Otherwise, I wish you luck!

Comment: None of your options are able to uniquely identify you, those are also available at best for your coworkers (or for geo-location for everybody e.g. in the same building on different floor). So I don't think there would be a way to unlock your laptop using any of those triggers.

Comment: @Máté, you are correct. It is a security risk. I'm looking to ignore that in favor of my convenience.

Comment: @SAR622: I didn't only mean it's a security risk, I meant those are not appropriate way of identifications, you probably won't be able to use them.